# Solving summation when $i$ and $j$ are dependent: $\sum\sum_{0 \leq i <j \leq n}1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How to solve the **summation** when the indices $i$ and $j$ are dependent?

Please, anybody, explain. I am having no idea how to proceed.

> Find the sum $$\sum_{0 \leq i <}\sum_{\!\!j \leq n}1$$

Comment: I am a highschool student who just want explaination please don't close my question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The domain of the integer pairs $(i,j)$ such that

$$0\le i<j\le n$$ is a triangle inside the square of size $n+1$ by $n+1$, diagonal excluded. Summing the term $1$ means that you just count those elements.

Hence you compute the area of the square minus the diagonal, and halve, giving

$$\frac{(n+1)^2-(n+1)}2=\frac{n(n+1)}2.$$

[image]

Comment: How are the number of terms $ (n+1) $?

Comment: @Kaushik: what else ?

Comment: According to my interpretation, it should be $ n $. This is because from left to right there are *n columns*.

Comment: @Kaushik: there are $n+1$ columns, recount.

Comment: Does it start from 0 in the above case? ( As it is mentioned, $ 0≤ i < j ≤ n $ )

Comment: @Kaushik: obviously.

Answer (score 2):

Note that you can convert the expression into:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\bigg(\sum_{j=i+1}^n 1\bigg) = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (n-i) = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} n - \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} i = n^2-\frac{n(n-1)}{2} = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$

When you see double sums like that, try breaking it up into individual sums. If one index (in this case, $j$) is conditional on another ($i$), the limit(s) of the dependent index can be expressed in terms of the other index. There's no reference/resource as such that comes to my mind, but it should get easier as you solve more and more such problems.

Comment: Sir can u provide additional resources regarding this question

Answer (score 0):

We have that

$$\mathop{\sum\sum}_{0\le i<j\le n} 1=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \left(\sum_{j=i+1}^n 1\right)=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (n-i)=n\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}1-\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} i=n\cdot n-\frac{n(n-1)}{2}=\frac{n(n+1)}2$$

Comment: (second last inequality) if $n=4$, the second term is $6$, whereas $n(n+1)/2 = 10$?

Comment: @ShirishKulhari thanks I fix!

Answer (score 0):

For every pair $(i,j)$ with $0\leq i<j\leq2$ you must add $1$, so the summation  gives you the number of such pairs, which is:$$\binom{n+1}2=\frac{n(n+1)}2$$